# Rails files not updating unless server restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project, and each time I want my changes to take effect (views, controllers, anything really) I am forced to close the server and restart it. I tried to find a solution to this but Googling it didn't help me at all. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `config/environments/development.rb` and add these two configs or change them to false

```
config.cache_classes = false
config.eager_load = false
```